# Query in Firebase doesn't work

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to get value "1507783288.001401" from Firebase in my Swift App. The following code doesn't return any results:

```
fireBase.child("metrics")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    .queryStarting(atValue: 1507705200.0)
    .queryEnding(atValue: 1507791599)
```

However, if I change "queryEnding" to 1507791598 it will return "1507783288.001401".

The values I'm storing as a timestamp is Swift's Double "timeIntervalSince1970".

I found this but I'm not sure if that means if I can't store those timestamps in Firebase:

> Numeric priorities are stored and ordered as IEEE 754 double-precision
>   floating-point numbers. Keys are always stored as strings and are
>   treated as numeric only when they can be parsed as a 32-bit integer.

(from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data)

Comment: It probably has something to do with how the data is stored in Firebase. Can you please include a snippet of your Firebase data structure as *text* please, no images. You can get the JSON using the Firebase console->Export JSON. Also, these are values, not keys so the quoted text doesn't apply here.